# Regression confidence using SVMs in python

Tags: python, margin, regression, svm

I'm using regression SVMs in python and I am wondering if there is any way to get a "confidence-measure" value for its predictions.

Previously, when using SVMs for binary classification, I was able to compute a confidence-type value from the 'margin'. Here is some pseudo-code showing how I got a confidence value:

```
# Begin pseudo-code
import svm as svmlib

prob = svmlib.svm_problem(labels, data)
param = svmlib.svm_parameter(svm_type=svmlib.C_SVC, kernel_type = svmlib.RBF)
model = svmlib.svm_model(prob, param)

# get confidence
confidence = self.model.predict_values_raw(sample_to_classify)
```

I imagine that the further the new sample is from the training data, the worse the confidence, but I'm looking for a function that might help compute a reasonable estimate for this.

My (high-level) problem is as follows:

- I have a function F(x), where x is a high-dimensional vector
- F(x) can be computed but it is very slow
- I want to train a regression SVM to approximate it
- If I can find values of 'x' that have low prediction confidence, I can add these points and retrain (aka. active learning)

Has anyone obtained/used regression-SVM confidence/margin values before?

Comment: Might want to try this question at http://metaoptimize.com/qa it's a SO clone for the machine learning community.

Comment: You will get a quicker answer to your problem at http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will check out those sites.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this similar response on Stack back in January. The chosen answer was spot on regarding how hard it is to get confidence measures on non-parametric fitting methods. There's probably some Bayesian type thing you could do, but that's probably not possible with the Python SVM library: [Prefer one class in libsvm (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756937/prefer-one-class-in-libsvm-python).

Comment: Hmmm, that question refers to SVM classification, but I'm looking for a solution for SVM 'Regression'

Comment: Okay. Regression and Classification are basically the same side of the coin. In the parametric modeling world we start by making assumptions about the model, how errors are distributed, etc. and that forms the basis for how we evaluate how well the model fits. Given a non-parametric approach like SVM, you're going to have to use some type of cross-validation technique (i.e., train on learn set, validate with test set) and you're looking for some type of Bayesian-driven proxy for goodness of fit. That's why I pointed out that link.