# Confidence for regression using Skit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, svm

How can I compute a confidence score for a regression prediction (e.g. using Support Vector Regression or Stochastic Gradient Descent regression) with Scikit-Learn?

In case of classification Skit-Learn enable to set

`clf = SVC(probability=True)`

and later use

`predict_proba()`

to get a classification with a confidence score. Those types of methods are not available for regression algorithms.

I do understand it can be easier to compute a score for classification algorithms (e.g. distance to hyperplane in case of SVM classifier), however is there a good approach to compute a prediction score in case of a regression?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more preferably with example?

Comment: duplicate [regression-confidence-using-svms-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148168/regression-confidence-using-svms-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: @sgDysregulation Thanks for your comment. While the question you are referring is similar and interesting, this question is actually not a duplicate as the question is about the Skit-Learn library while the other one is about SVMLib library

Comment: @VivekKumar I added more details.

Comment: If you need a confidence you are better off using other methods, such as gaussian processes

Comment: Since regression problems are predicting a continuous target variable, there are infinitely many values that variable can take and those many confidence scores are possible. How do you think the algorithm should reflect this? Maybe you are thinking about variance or such measures. Please [have a look here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics)